# How to execute an IN lookup in SQL using Golang?

Tags: sql, go

What does Go want for the second param in this SQL query.
I am trying to use the `IN` lookup in postgres.

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("SELECT * FROM awesome_table WHERE id= $1 AND other_field IN $2")
rows, err := stmt.Query(10, ???)
```

What I really want:

```
SELECT * FROM awesome_table WHERE id=10 AND other_field IN (this, that);
```

Comment: Relevant Go issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16235

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Query just takes varargs to replace the params in your sql
so, in your example, you would just do

```
rows, err := stmt.Query(10)
```

say, this and that of your second example were dynamic, then you'd do

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("SELECT * FROM awesome_table WHERE id=$1 AND other_field IN ($2, $3)")
rows, err := stmt.Query(10,"this","that")
```

If you have variable args for the "IN" part, you can do ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/oagPvpxP7-))

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    stuff := []interface{}{"this", "that", "otherthing"}
    sql := "select * from foo where id=? and name in (?" + strings.Repeat(",?", len(stuff)-1) + ")"
    fmt.Println("SQL:", sql)
    args := []interface{}{10}
    args = append(args, stuff...)
    fakeExec(args...)
    // This also works, but I think it's harder for folks to read
    //fakeExec(append([]interface{}{10},stuff...)...)
}

func fakeExec(args ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Println("Got:", args)
}
```

Comment: What if there are a varying amount of items for the in clause?

Comment: So I get this and this would work. I guess I'm expecting the sql driver to convert a slice or something to the appropriate thing.
Ex:
```stmt, err := db.Prepare("SELECT * FROM awesome_table WHERE id= $1 AND other_field IN $2")```

```args:= []int{1,3,4,5}```

```rows, err := stmt.Query(10, args)```

Comment: Yep, that would be better.  Always wanted that on the Java side as well.  Databases would need to natively support it as the SQL part is sent unchanged to the server and the args are sent separately (seems like no database supports list/array args)

Comment: You could opt to replace the construction of the series of question marks with `strings.Join(strings.Split(strings.Repeat("?", len(stuff)), ""), ",")`. I feel it's slightly less of an mental exercise. Of course you would need a guard statement against empty `stuff`.

Comment: Note that this solution gets a bit more involved in conjunction with [lib/pq](http://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Queries) due to its use of positional placeholders ($1, $2, etc.).

Comment: with pq, you can do `where other_field = ANY($2)` then pass `pq.StringArray(stuff)`.  Way better than computing a where clause

Answer (score 63):

It looks like you may be using the [pq driver](https://github.com/lib/pq).  `pq` recently added Postgres-specific Array support via [pq.Array](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Array) (see [pull request 466](https://github.com/lib/pq/pull/466)).  You can get what you want via:

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("SELECT * FROM awesome_table WHERE id= $1 AND other_field = ANY($2)")
rows, err := stmt.Query(10, pq.Array([]string{'this','that'})
```

I think this generates the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM awesome_table WHERE id=10 AND other_field = ANY('{"this", "that"}');
```

Note this utilizes prepared statements, so the inputs should be sanitized.

Comment: This is the best option, since it has no injection risks and allows re-use of the same prepared statement (which improves performance compared to the currently accepted answer)

Answer (score 26):

Incase anyone like me was trying to use an array with a query, here is an easy solution.

get https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx

```
ids := []int{1, 2, 3}
q,args,err := sqlx.In("SELECT id,username FROM users WHERE id IN(?);", ids) //creates the query string and arguments
//you should check for errors of course
q = sqlx.Rebind(sqlx.DOLLAR,q) //only if postgres
rows, err := db.Query(q,args...) //use normal POSTGRES/ANY SQL driver important to include the '...' after the Slice(array)
```

Comment: I shall add that it also supports multiple parameters: `name := "foobar"` `q,args,err := sqlx.In("SELECT id,username FROM users WHERE id IN(?) AND name = (?);", ids, name)`

Comment: How can we make below query: select * from student where (name, surname) IN (("eduncan", "911"), ("somesh","sing") .....) ?

Comment: `important to include the '...' after the Slice(array)` saved my life.

Answer (score 20):

> With PostgreSQL, at least, you have the option of passing the entire array as a string, using a single placeholder:

```
db.Query("select 1 = any($1::integer[])", "{1,2,3}")
```

> That way, you can use a single query string, and all the string concatenation is confined to the parameter. And if the parameter is malformed, you don't get an SQL injection; you just get something like: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "xyz"

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/vHbg09g7s2I/RKU7XsO25SIJ

Answer (score 7):

if you use sqlx, you can follow this way:
https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/issues/346

```
arr := []string{"this", "that"}
query, args, err := sqlx.In("SELECT * FROM awesome_table WHERE id=10 AND other_field IN (?)", arr)
 
query = db.Rebind(query) // sqlx.In returns queries with the `?` bindvar, rebind it here for matching the database in used (e.g. postgre, oracle etc, can skip it if you use mysql)
rows, err := db.Query(query, args...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var awesome AwesomeStruct
var awesomes []*AwesomeStruct

ids := []int{1,2,3,4}
q, args, err := sqlx.In(`
  SELECT * FROM awesome_table WHERE id=(?) AND other_field IN (?)`, 10, ids)

// use .Select for multiple return
err = db.Select(&awesomes, db.SQL.Rebind(q), args...)

// use .Get for single return
err = db.Get(&awesome, db.SQL.Rebind(q), args...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//I tried a different way. A simpler and easier way, maybe not too efficient.
stringedIDs := fmt.Sprintf("%v", ids)
stringedIDs = stringedIDs[1 : len(stringedIDs)-1]
stringedIDs = strings.ReplaceAll(stringedIDs, " ", ",")
query := "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ("  + stringedIDs + ")"
//Then follow your standard database/sql Query
rows, err := db.Query(query)
//error checking
if err != nil {
    // Handle errors
} else {
    // Process rows
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather pedestrian and only to be used if server generated. Where UserIDs is a slice (list) of strings:

```
sqlc := `select count(*) from test.Logins where UserID 
                in ("` + strings.Join(UserIDs,`","`) + `")`
errc := db.QueryRow(sqlc).Scan(&Logins)
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yes, that's why it says "only to be used if server generated". Injection attacks are only from user input. Anyway, there is nothing to stop the use of db.Prepare on sqlc.

Answer (score -3):

You can also use this direct conversion.

```
awesome_id_list := []int{3,5,8}

var str string
for _, value := range awesome_id_list {
        str += strconv.Itoa(value) + ","
}

query := "SELECT * FROM awesome_table WHERE id IN (" + str[:len(str)-1] + ")"
```

**WARNING**
This is method is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Use this method only if `awesome_id_list` is server generated.

Comment: Isn't this gonna remove the sanity check and make SQL injection possible?

Comment: @SongGao You are correect. That's why it shouldn't be used with user input. I'm adding a warning for that case

Comment: I would stay away from this suggestion. The risk is minimal but "only paranoid survive". If "server" generates unexpected inputs, db could be injected.

Comment: If your array is of ints, its safe, if it was an array of strings you should be worry about sql injection...