# Go and IN clause in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, go

I am trying to execute the following query against the PostgreSQL database in Go using [pq driver](https://github.com/lib/pq):

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM tags
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

where `1, 2, 3` is passed at a slice `tags := []string{"1", "2", "3"}`.

I have tried many different things like:

```
s := "(" + strings.Join(tags, ",") + ")"
if err := Db.QueryRow(`
    SELECT COUNT(id)
    FROM tags
    WHERE id IN $1`, s,
).Scan(&num); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

which results in `pq: syntax error at or near "$1"`. I also tried

```
if err := Db.QueryRow(`
    SELECT COUNT(id)
    FROM tags
    WHERE id IN ($1)`, strings.Join(stringTagIds, ","),
).Scan(&num); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

which also fails with `pq: invalid input syntax for integer: "1,2,3"`

I also tried passing a slice of integers/strings directly and got `sql: converting Exec argument #0's type: unsupported type []string, a slice`.

So how can I execute this query in Go?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [How to execute an IN lookup in SQL using Golang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271123/how-to-execute-an-in-lookup-in-sql-using-golang).

Comment: Thank you @MarioAlexandroSantini. Will take a looks. It is disappointing that I have not found it (I actually looked)

Comment: I suggest you to use some library that handles this cases for you, without reinventing the wheel. [igor](https://github.com/galeone/igor#where-1) handles this (and other) case for you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Pre-building the SQL query (preventing SQL injection)

If you're generating an SQL string with a param placeholder for each of the values, it's easier to just generate the final SQL right away.

Note that since values are `string`s, there's place for SQL injection attack, so we first test if all the `string` values are indeed numbers, and we only proceed if so:

```
tags := []string{"1", "2", "3"}
buf := bytes.NewBufferString("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tags WHERE id IN(")
for i, v := range tags {
    if i > 0 {
        buf.WriteString(",")
    }
    if _, err := strconv.Atoi(v); err != nil {
        panic("Not number!")
    }
    buf.WriteString(v)
}
buf.WriteString(")")
```

Executing it:

```
num := 0
if err := Db.QueryRow(buf.String()).Scan(&num); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

#### Using `ANY`

You can also use [Postgresql's `ANY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-comparisons.html), whose syntax is as follows:

```
expression operator ANY (array expression)
```

Using that, our query may look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tags WHERE id = ANY('{1,2,3}'::int[])
```

In this case you can declare the text form of the array as a parameter:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tags WHERE id = ANY($1::int[])
```

Which can simply be built like this:

```
tags := []string{"1", "2", "3"}
param := "{" + strings.Join(tags, ",") + "}"
```

Note that no check is required in this case as the array expression will not allow SQL injection (but rather will result in a query execution error).

So the full code:

```
tags := []string{"1", "2", "3"}

q := "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tags WHERE id = ANY($1::int[])"
param := "{" + strings.Join(tags, ",") + "}"

num := 0
if err := Db.QueryRow(q, param).Scan(&num); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add that these days there are quite a few libraries trying to simplify database use in go. Particularly for MySQL and PostgreSQL. And many simplify passing IN parameters as well. For example, gocraft/dbr and jmoiron/sqlx come to mind.

Comment: I find that the array constructor syntax (`array[1,2,3]`) is easier to use than than braces (`'{1,2,3}'::int[]`) for PostgreSQL arrays, fewer quoting problems. Of course that means that you'd have to produce a list of placeholders (`array[$1,$2,$3]`) but that's easy enough.

Comment: Instead of all the `stings.Join` stuff, you can now just pass in `pq.Array(tags)`. So you'd have `Db.QueryRow("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tags WHERE id = ANY($1::int[])", pq.Array(tags))`

Answer (score 7):

This is not really a Golang issue, you are using a string to compare to integer (id) in your SQL request. That means, SQL receive:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM tags
WHERE id IN ("1, 2, 3")
```

instead of what you want to give it. You just need to convert your tags into integer and passe it to the query.

EDIT:
Since you are trying to pass multiple value to the query, then you should tell it:

```
params := make([]string, 0, len(tags))
for i := range tags {
    params = append(params, fmt.Sprintf("$%d", i+1))
}
query := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tags WHERE id IN (%s)", strings.Join(params, ", "))
```

This will end the query with a "($1, $2, $3...", then convert your tags as int:

```
values := make([]int, 0, len(tags))
for _, s := range tags {
    val, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
    if err != nil {
        // Do whatever is required with the error
        fmt.Println("Err : ", err)
    } else {
        values = append(values, val)
    }
}
```

And finally, you can use it in the query:

```
Db.QueryRow(query, values...)
```

This should do it.

Comment: and this is exactly what I am asking about. How to do this. The problem is that your answer does not explain how to achieve it.

Comment: I think this will not work now it is expecting interface{} and it will give the error "Cannot use xxx (type []int) as type []interface {} in argument to DB.QueryContext"

Answer (score 5):

Extending **@icza** solution, you can use [`pq.Array`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq@v1.10.6?utm_source=gopls#Array) instead of building the params yourself.

So using his example, the code can look like this:

```golang
tags := []string{"1", "2", "3"}

q := "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tags WHERE id = ANY($1::int[])"

num := 0
if err := Db.QueryRow(q, pq.Array(tags)).Scan(&num); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `sqlx`:

```golang
var ids = []string{"1", "2", "3"}
query, args, err := sqlx.In("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tags WHERE id IN (?);", ids)
 
// sqlx.In returns queries with the `?` bindvar, we can rebind it for our backend
query = db.Rebind(query)
rows, err := db.Query(query, args...)
```