# Go postgres `SELECT * IN` using array

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a simple select statement:

`Select * FROM X where X.name in ("bob", "joe") and X.phone='123'`

That works fine in postgres,

In my Go code I have the following code:

```
var phone string = "123"
var names []string = []string{"bob", "joe"}
sqlStatement := `Select * FROM X where X.name in ($1) and X.phone=$2`
rows, sqlerr := db.Query(sqlStatement, names, phone)
```

but for some reason I error out from that sql.

> unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type  into type *string

how can i use my names array in side the sqlstatement?

note: if i do a fmt.printf and paste the sql statement into postgres, i do get data back + if i take out the $1, and manually input the strings

Comment: Use `X.name = ANY ($1)` with [`lib/pq` array types](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#StringArray).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go and IN clause in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036752/go-and-in-clause-in-postgres)

Answer (score 6):

Copying and pasting fragments from some working Go PostgreSQL code:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/lib/pq"
)

    query := `
            . . .
            WHERE code = ANY($1)
           . . .

        `

    codes := []string{"JFK", "LGA", "EWR"}
    rows, err := db.Query(query, pq.Array(codes))
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#inQueries

```
var phone string = "123"
var names []string = []string{"bob", "joe"}
sqlStatement := `Select * FROM X where X.name in (?) and X.phone=?`
sqlStatement, args, err := sqlx.In(sqlStatement, names, phone)
sqlStatement = db.Rebind(sqlStatement)
        rows, sqlerr := db.Queryx(sqlStatement, args...)
```

this now returns correctly.

another way to solve this was to use `fmt.Sprintf()` and converting the `?` to `%s`