# Postgres select WHERE col1, col2 IN with 2d golang slice

Tags: postgresql, go

I am not sure how to make postgres query where (col1, col2) in 2dslice

I have tried the following:

`

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (
  id CHAR(27) NOT NULL,
  lat FLOAT8 NOT NULL,
  lon FLOAT8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


latlongdata := [][]float64{}
latlongdata = append(latlongdata, []float64{1.2, 2.3},)
latlongdata = append(latlongdata, []float64{1.3, 2.4},)
......................................
latlongdata = append(latlongdata, []float64{1.4, 2.5},)

fmt.Println(latlongdata)// prints [[1.2 2.3] [1.3 2.4] ....... [1.4 2.5]] (very long array)

Query: r.db.QueryContext(ctx,("SELECT id, lat, lon FROM table2 WHERE (lat, lon) IN $1", latlongdata,)
```

`

Can you please suggest how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go and IN clause in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036752/go-and-in-clause-in-postgres)

Comment: I don't think `value1,value2 in ...`  is  valid sql. You can rewrite the query as (lat=v1 and long=v2) or (lat=v2 and long=v4) or ...

Comment: Try running your sql statement through a validator like https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/

Comment: Updated my question. Can you please suggest the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```golang
Query: r.db.QueryContext(ctx,("SELECT id, lat, long FROM table2 WHERE lat, long IN (select $1, $2 union select $3, $4)", latlongdata[0][0], latlongdata[0][1], latlongdata[1][0], latlongdata[1][1])
```

or create and insert `latlongdata` into a temp table
then

```sql
WHERE lat, long IN (select filed1, field2 from temptable)
```