# How to use sqlx to query mysql IN a slice?

Tags: mysql, go, sqlx

I want to query a table in mysql database for values `IN` a slice:

```
var qids []int
//fill qids dynamically
err = database.SQL.Select(&quotes,
    "SELECT * FROM quote WHERE qid IN $1", qids)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

But I get this error:

```
sql: converting Exec argument #0's type: unsupported type []int, a slice
quotes []
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go and IN clause in Postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036752/go-and-in-clause-in-postgres); and [Golang MySQL querying undefined amount of args using IN operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223856/golang-mysql-querying-undefined-amount-of-args-using-in-operator).

Comment: @icza I don't think so. This about a feature that is only available in `sqlx`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

sqlx has a great helper for that: [In()](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#In) we just have to prepare the query by taking the args and Rebind, like this:

```
var qids []int

// fills qids on query dynamically
query, args, err := sqlx.In("SELECT * FROM quote WHERE qid IN (?)", qids)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// sqlx.In returns queries with the `?` bindvar, we can rebind it for our backend
//
query = database.SQL.Rebind(query)  // database.SQL should be a *sqlx.DB

err = database.SQL.Select(&quotes, query, args...)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// or just in one line:

err = database.SQL.Select(&quotes, database.SQL.Rebind(query), args...)
```

Also I recommend you take a look here: http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/ there're a lot of examples including **IN**

Comment: It is much more convoluted that I wished to be, but works nonetheless. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

The tags suggest that you are using `sqlx`. It has [support for `IN`](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#inQueries) in queries.

So you can do

```
var qids []int
//fill qids dynamically
rows, err = db.Query(&quotes, "SELECT * FROM quote WHERE qid IN ($1)", qids)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
// scan the rows
```

Comment: Yes I use `sqlx` but not sure why I still get the same error.

Comment: this one worked for me, just replace `$1` with `?` if you are using mysql.

Answer (score -3):

Hey its because of []int
try this

```
type Int64Array []int64

// Value returns the driver compatible value
func (a Int64Array) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
var strs []string
for _, i := range a {
    strs = append(strs, strconv.FormatInt(i, 10))
}
return "{" + strings.Join(strs, ",") + "}", nil
}
```

and then pass int64 to query

```
db.Queryx("SELECT * FROM quote WHERE qid IN $1", int64IDs)
```

**for more detail check [here](http://www.dammitjim.co.uk/blog/golang-using-pq-sqlx-slices/)**