# golang slice in mysql query with where in clause

Tags: go

I am running the below query, but only get the first id value:-

```
select * from `table` where table`.`id` in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '9', '11', '13', '14', '15', '17') and `table`.`deleted_at` is null
```

I have done the following:-

```
var aID = make([]string, 0)
var in India // india is struct

for rows.Next() {
    cook := rows.Scan(&in.ID)

    aID = append(aID, strconv.Itoa(in.ID))
}

asID = strings.Join(aID, ",")

anotherRow,err := db.Query("SELECT * from table2 where id in (?)", asID)
if err != nil { fmt.Printf("Error: ", err) }
// ... Other line follows up with "for anotherRow.Next() and fetching"
```

While fetching data, it only returns value of "1" and ignores all other ID passed to it, which are `'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '9', '11', '13', '14', '15', '17'`.

How can I pass it correctly?

I am using `go-sql-driver/mysql`.

FAQ :

1. `aID` does contain all those numbers as string and
2. table has all the rows available with provided above `id`.
3. `table` is from where `id` is fetched and appended to `aID` and another record with `id` stored in `aID` are fetched with `in` statement from `table2`.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have all of these ids in table2?

Comment: obviously yes, I am able to run mysql query inside mysql cli with all those id and getting return for all.

Comment: You can use `sqlx.In` to solve this. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40565805/how-to-use-sqlx-to-query-mysql-in-a-slice/40567910#40567910

Comment: Cool, just one thing - your sample sql query uses `table`, query in yoour code uses `table2`. Not sure if relevant.

Comment: @Nebril, `table` is from where id is fetched and appended to `aID` and another records with `id` stored in `aID` are fetched with `in` statement from `table2`.

Comment: @yazgazan, No plan to use completely new package for just 1 query. I am using `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`

Comment: Are you calling anotherRow.Next() ? You don't show how do you try to access rows.

Comment: `github.com/jmoiron/sqlx` is widely used and extremely convenient. It does not replace `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` but is a "drop in" replacement for `database/sql`.

Comment: @JohnCargo your example query shows the ids quoted in single quotes, strconv.Itoa and strings.Join will not result in `'1','2','3',...` but in `1,2,3,...`.

Comment: @mkopriva, yes they are resulting in `1,2,3,..` are they different from `'1', '2', '3' ...` - is there any function which can convert them to `'1', '2'` without writing `for` loop ?

Comment: @JohnCargo the '?' placeholder gets replaced with the string of numbers separated by commas, so the query results in `WHERE id IN ('1,2,3,4...')` and mysql matches only the first value in that string, so id equal to `1` or `'1'` will match but id equal to `2` or `'2'` will not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go and IN clause in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036752/go-and-in-clause-in-postgres/38037586#38037586).

Comment: @mkopriva , Ok, i see what it does now. Is there any way to format as per requirement without doing `for` loop.

Comment: @icza - this is mysql and it's different.

Comment: @JohnCargo I know, but the first solution in that answer is not postgres specific, so it works with mysql as well.

Comment: you could use sqlx  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40565805/how-to-use-sqlx-to-query-mysql-in-a-slice

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
args := make([]interface{}, len(asID))
for i, id := range asID {
    args[i] = id
}
stmt := `SELECT * from table2 where id in (?` + strings.Repeat(",?", len(args)-1) + `)`
anotherRow, err := db.Query(stmt, args...)
```

Just note you will want to put in a guard if `asID` can ever have len == 0.

If you have any other arguments to pass in, you'll have to add them to the `args` slice.

Also to note, you should explicitly name the columns you want so you can guarantee you are scanning in the correct columns to the correct fields.

Comment: This is a good solution, because it also prevents sql injection.

Comment: I was just about to do something similar but thought "somebody must have done it already", very clever

Comment: Why not

 `SELECT * from table2 where id in (` + strings.Trim(string(asID), "[]") + `)`

Comment: @Illud 
1) Because that does not compile (`cannot convert []string{…} (value of type []string) to type string`). 
2) Even if that did compile, it seems a bit hacky. 
3) Using parameters allows you to avoid SQL injection, while your proposed way would not.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
q,args,err := sqlx.In("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id IN(?);", asID) //creates the query string and arguments
rows, err := db.Query(q,args...)
```

You could also use the [Masterminds/squirrel](https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel) package:

```
import sq "github.com/Masterminds/squirrel"

...

users := sq.Select("*").From("table2")
active := users.Where(sq.Eq{"id":[]string{"1","2","3"}})
sql, args, err := active.ToSql()
```

Which will do the `in clause` automatically when using sq.Eq struct with a slice.

Comment: Any possibility without importing any further package ?

Comment: have you tried? `db.Query("SELECT * from table2 where id in (?)", aID...)`

Comment: @JohnCargo you need to make `aID` of type `[]interface{}`. The why is too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this.

```
func GetPlaceholders(values ...string) (placeholders string, parameters []interface{}) {
    n := len(values)
    p := make([]string, n)
    parameters = make([]interface{}, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        p[i] = "?"
        parameters[i] = values[i]
    }
    placeholders = strings.Join(p, ",")
    return placeholders, parameters
}
```

and calling the function like this

```
placeholders, params := GetPlaceholders("1", "2", "3")

rows, err := db.Query(`select language, textkey, text 
        from language where textkey in (`+placeholders+`)
        order by language, textkey`, params...)
```

Answer (score -1):

The most elegant solution for queries to make array/slice work directly with sql queries. This also sql injection proof as you are not using string concatenation rather using sql prepared statement

```
idAry := []string{"1", "2", "3"}
q := "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = any($1);"
rows, err := db.Exec(q, pq.Array(authors))
```

Comment: OP states they are using `mysql`, so `postgresql` syntax won't work here.

Answer (score -2):

Since you're dealing with ids from your own database and if you are certain there is no way someone could inject malicious "ids" into that code, don't use the placeholder `?` and just use the `fmt` package.

```
fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * from table2 where id in (%s)", asID)
```

this will result in `SELECT * from table2 where id in (1,2,3,4...)` as opposed to `SELECT * from table2 where id in ('1,2,3,4...')`

Comment: Just leaving note for future readers : Though i have selected this answer and this answer is safe for given question. But as the answer above says, the query runs without escaping the arguments , so, this code should not be used where malicious user can inject malicious ID.

Comment: This is how sql injection happens, one genius is writing some code that is 'only' used with strings of known origin and then 1 year later, second genius is using that already written and battle tested function in different context :), usualy after the first genius already left the company.

Answer (score -3):

example:

```
idAry := []string{"1", "2", "3"}
ids := strings.Join(idAry, "','")
sqlRaw := fmt.Sprintf(`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ('%s')`, ids)
rows, err := db.Query(sqlRaw)
```

It works fine

Comment: This solution can allow a [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack

Comment: This allows sql injection when the strings are user controlled