# How to query using an IN clause and a `Vec` as parameter in Rust sqlx for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, rust, rust-sqlx

Note: this is a similar but NOT duplicate question with [How to use sqlx to query mysql IN a slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40565805/how-to-use-sqlx-to-query-mysql-in-a-slice). I'm asking for [the Rust one](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx).

This is what I try to do.

```
let v = vec![..];
sqlx::query("SELECT something FROM table WHERE column IN (?)").bind(v)
 ...
```

Then I got the following error

```
the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<u64>: sqlx::Encode<'_, _>` is not satisfied
```

Comment: You currently can't.

Comment: Any workaround (making the SQL query manually? Any tips of preventing injection if I do so?) is also welcomed.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.5.9/sqlx/trait.Encode.html#impl-Encode%3C%27q%2C%20Postgres%3E-for-Vec%3CT%2C%20Global%3E), it looks like this is only possible for the PostgreSQL backend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer is in first on FAQ https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/blob/master/FAQ.md

> **How can I do a SELECT ... WHERE foo IN (...) query?** In 0.6 SQLx will
> support binding arrays as a comma-separated list for every database,
> but unfortunately there's no general solution for that currently in
> SQLx itself. You would need to manually generate the query, at which
> point it cannot be used with the macros.

Answer (score 10):

The error shows `Vec` is not an `Encode` that is required to be as a valid DB value. The `Encode` [doc](https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.5.5/sqlx/trait.Encode.html) lists all the Rust types that have implemented the trait. `Vec` is not one.

You can use the following way to bind the parameters in **IN** with the values of a vector. Firstly, you need to expand the number of '?' in the IN expression to be the same number of the parameters. Then, you need to call `bind` to bind the values one by one.

```
let v = vec![1, 2];

let params = format!("?{}", ", ?".repeat(v.len()-1));
let query_str = format!("SELECT id FROM test_table WHERE id IN ( { } )", params);

let mut query = sqlx::query(&query_str);
for i in v {
    query = query.bind(i);
}

let row = query.fetch_all(&pool).await?;
```

**NB: Please note if the target database is not MySql, you need to use $n, like $1, $2, instead of ?, as the parameter placeholder.**

Answer (score 1):

The following definitely works for PostgreSQL. Not tested for MySQL:

```
let ids = vec![1, 2, 3];
sqlx::query!(
        "
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            foo
        WHERE
            id IN (SELECT unnest($1::integer[]))
        ",
        ids as Vec<i32>
    )...
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `Query::bind()` , there is [`MySqlArguments`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/mysql/struct.MySqlArguments.html) (as of `v0.7.3`) that allows you to dynamically bind arbitrary number of values to a [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) at runtime.

Here is a typical way to use it :

- create struct object [`MySqlStatement`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/mysql/struct.MySqlStatement.html) which implements [the trait `Statement`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/trait.Statement.html). Pass the SQL string with some placeholders (e.g. `?` in MySQL), based on number of items in the given `Vec<...>`
- create a `MySqlArguments` object and gather values from the provided `Vec<...>`
- bind the arguments in `MySqlArguments` to `MySqlStatement` object , then convert it to prepared query.

  - the number of the placeholders has to match number of values added to `MySqlArguments`

The code may look like this :

```rust
use sqlx::{PoolConnection, MySql, Query};
use sqlx::mysql::MySqlArguments;

// acquire connection from pool
let conn : PoolConnection<MySql> = ... ;
let v = vec![...];

let placehoders = (0..v.len()).into_iter().map(|_| "?")
                  .collect::<Vec<&str>>();
let sql_pattern = format!(
    "SELECT columns FROM table WHERE column IN ({})" ,
    placehoders.join(",")
);
let mut args = MySqlArguments::default();
v.into_iter().map(|item| args.add(item)).count();


let stmt = conn.prepare(sql_pattern.as_str());
let query: Query<MySql, MySqlArguments> = stmt.query_with(args);
```