# How to join array of strings?

Tags: go, buffalo

I have an API where I send a parameter `currentList: ["hey", "cool"]`

```
type sentenceCreateReq struct {
    CurrentList []string `json:"currentList"`
}

func (usr *SentenceResource) Create(c buffalo.Context) error {
    req := sentenceCreateReq{}
    parseReqBody(c.Request(), &req)

    ...

    sentence := models.Sentence{}
    err := tx.Limit(1).Where("word NOT IN (?)", c.Params("currentList")).First(&sentence)

    ...
}
```

How would I be able to join the array of strings to fit my requirement?

The SQL statement I want to run is

`SELECT * FROM sentences WHERE word NOT IN ('hey', 'cool');`

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Go and IN clause in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036752/go-and-in-clause-in-postgres/38037586#38037586); and [Golang MySQL querying undefined amount of args using IN operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223856/golang-mysql-querying-undefined-amount-of-args-using-in-operator/39223999#39223999).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you will need a number of placeholders equal to the length of the slice you are passing in

like this, for example:
https://play.golang.org/p/AZRTUsfKyH7

then something like

```
tx.Where(query, sentence...)
```

which will pass in the slice as separate arguments to fill in the placeholders.