# How to join array of Strings? SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, inner-join

I want to make a join between the table people and vehicles, which both share this value,

in the people table the field is `vehicles`

```
["https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/14/","https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/30/"]
```

and in the vehicles table the field is `url`

```
https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/14/
```

As you can see in the first one there is like a list of strings, how could I do the query? is sqlite

I tried this, but does not work

```
SELECT *
FROM people
INNER JOIN vehicles
ON people.vehicles = vehicles.url
```

you can see the endpoints here:
https://swapi.dev/api/people/
https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/

also i see this post [How to join array of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49695655/how-to-join-array-of-strings)
but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: SQLite does not support arrays.  What is the actual data in the `vehicles` column in the `people` table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this: 
`["https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/14/","https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/30/"]` thats the data

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM people
INNER JOIN vehicles
ON people.vehicles like '%'+ vehicles.url  +'%'
```

Comment: Hi , that's return me nothing, does not work :/ please can keep me helping?

Comment: 0

SELECT *
FROM people
INNER JOIN vehicles
ON people.vehicles like CONCAT('%', vehicles.url ,'%')