# Golang db query using slice IN clause

Tags: sql, go, slice

Can someone explain to me why this does not work?

```
inq := "6,7" //strings.Join(artIds, ",")
rows, err = db.Query("SELECT DISTINCT title FROM tags_for_articles LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_for_articles.tag_id WHERE article_id IN (?)", inq)
```

And this does

```
rows, err = db.Query("SELECT DISTINCT title FROM tags_for_articles LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_for_articles.tag_id WHERE article_id IN (6,7)", inq)
```

I'm trying to do a simple IN clause with a slice of ints, and every solution suggested doesn't seem very idiomatic

Tried to do this, but the problem appears to be the string substitution.

```
inq := strings.Join(artIds, ",")
```

I'm a bit surprised that go doesn't seem to have a graceful way to handle this query.

Comment: *Why* is because `inq` is a string so if you parameterize it your going to end up with `IN ('6,7')` which is valid but a very different thing.  As a general rule an `IN` cannot be parameterized. Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271123/how-to-execute-an-in-lookup-in-sql-using-golang

Comment: Thanks, I suspected something like that. Yeah I saw the interface repeat thing, but it just smells a bit funky to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute an IN lookup in SQL using Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271123/how-to-execute-an-in-lookup-in-sql-using-golang)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have been careful to build your inq string from real ints (to avoid injection), you can just build the string yourself and avoid using ?:

```
inq := "6,7" 
sql := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT DISTINCT title FROM tags_for_articles LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_for_articles.tag_id WHERE article_id IN (%s)",inq)
rows, err := db.Query(sql)
```

If you do it a lot, better to have a WhereIn function that does this for you, or use an orm. Be careful which args you accept though, as if you accept arbitrary strings anything could be injected.

Comment: I'm quite new to go so this is something I would be a bit wary of in a dynamically typed language. However, in my code inq is generated from a slice of type ints, so they are definitely ints. Is this good practice tho?

Comment: If you make sure they are ints, I see no problem with it. Any function you write should take ints, not a string.

Comment: Ok thanks, this seems like the simplest solution. It's actually for a technical test so I might just caveat the hell out of it and show it's been considered.

Answer (score 4):

> Because database/sql does not inspect your query and it passes your
>   arguments directly to the driver, it makes dealing with queries with
>   IN clauses difficult:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE level IN (?);
```

> When this gets prepared as a statement on the backend, the bindvar ?
>   will only correspond to a single argument, but what is often desired
>   is for that to be a variable number of arguments depending on the
>   length of some slice

```
var levels = []int{4, 6, 7}
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE level IN (?);", levels)
```

There is a way to handle these types of queries using [`sqlx` package](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/) which provide more control over database queries.

This pattern is possible by first processing the query with sqlx.In:

```
var levels = []int{4, 6, 7}
query, args, err := sqlx.In("SELECT * FROM users WHERE level IN (?);", levels)
```

For more information Go through Godoc for [InQueries](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#inQueries)

Comment: Thanks for the information, very valuable. That package looks good.

Answer (score 3):

You need the number of "?" in the "IN" clause to match the number of arguments , so you need to do something like this:

```
inq := "6,7" //strings.Join(artIds, ",")
qms := strings.Repeat("?,", len(inq))
qms = params[:len(params)-1] // remove the trailing ","

rows, err = db.Query("SELECT DISTINCT title FROM tags_for_articles LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_for_articles.tag_id WHERE article_id IN (" + qms + ")", inq)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem then I came up with another solution in more secure way. So, you don't need to aware of SQL injection.

```golang
params := []string{"A", "B"}
jsonParams, err := json.Marshal(params)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

rows, err = db.Query(`
 WITH compared_values as(
   SELECT * 
     FROM JSON_TABLE(
      ?,
      "$[*]" COLUMNS( 
       value TEXT PATH "$"
     )
   ) as compared_values
 ) 
 SELECT * FROM target_table
 WHERE target_value IN (SELECT value FROM compared_values);
`, jsonParams)
```

you can also use pure select part in SQL query like this but I'm not sure about performace. I think using WITH cause can prevent repeatly JSON parsing.

```sql
 SELECT * FROM  target_table
 WHERE target_value IN (
   SELECT value FROM JSON_TABLE(
     ?,
     "$[*]" COLUMNS( 
       value TEXT PATH "$"
     )
   ) as compared_values
  );
```